# Cannot insert + sign into database using nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
app.get ('/add',(req , res) => {
const name = req.query.name    


db.run('INSERT INTO type (name) VALUES (?)', [name], function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(err.message);
  }

  res.redirect('/')
});

  })
```

when I try to insert for example A- it records A- in the database while if i insert A+ it records only A . 
http://localhost:8081/add?name=A+

Comment: I think that your question is incomplete. For now, I note that `return res.send` is unnecessary since `res.send` interrupt the stack.

Comment: What database library are you using?

Comment: I use SQLite database

Comment: + is a reserved character, you will need to use URL encoding if you want to pass + in as a value in URL.

Comment: Here (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) you can get more info.